# Putting Azure Application Insights in Shared Project and writing logs to it using Serilog

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights, serilog

I have three projects inside a visual studio solution.

One is an ASP.NET MVC5 website called **Mat2**, the other is the Web API project called **Mat2.API** and the third one is a shared C# project called **Mat2.Common**

[image]

I am using Azure Application Insights inside the website and API projects. The configuration code and files/keys related to Azure Application Insights are placed inside both of these projects.

Before I go to my question, I would like to mention that I am using Serilog for logging. I have created my own Logger class and it is placed inside the **Mat2.Common** project.

Here is the code for it:

```
public class Logger
{
    private static readonly ILogger logger;

    static Logger()
    {
        logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.WithUserName(anonymousUsername: "Not Authenticated")
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.With(new ThreadEnrich())
            .Enrich.WithMachineName()
            .Enrich.WithHttpRequestId()
            .Enrich.WithHttpRequestNumber()
            .Enrich.WithHttpRequestClientHostIP()
            .Enrich.WithHttpRequestType()
            .Enrich.WithHttpRequestRawUrl()
            .Enrich.WithMvcRouteData()
            .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails(
                new DestructuringOptionsBuilder()
                .WithDefaultDestructurers())
            .WriteTo.RollingFile(new JsonFormatter(),
                HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath($"~/logs/log-.json"),
                LogEventLevel.Debug,
                fileSizeLimitBytes: 655360)
            .CreateLogger();
    }

    public static void LogInformation(string info, object[] data = null)
    {
        logger.Information(info, data);
    }

    public static void LogDebug(string debug, object[] data = null)
    {
        logger.Debug(debug, data);
    }

    public static void LogWarning(string warning, object[] data = null, Exception e = null)
    {
        logger.Warning(e, warning, data);
    }

    public static void LogError(Exception e, string error, object[] data = null)
    {
        logger.Error(e, error, data);
    }
}
```

I want to write the logs produced by Serilog to Azure Application Insights inside the **Mat2.Common** project. Based on the very little I know about Azure Application Insights, it is installed/configured inside the website and API projects separately.

Is it possible to centralize the Azure Application Insights functionality just as the logging related functionality is centralized by putting it in the shared project?

The thing is that Azure Application Insights is a subscription-based product that is configured in an ASP.NET project. We pay for API and Website projects separately. While I am thinking of moving it to the shared C# project and then use it in two ASP.NET projects from the shared project.

I don't want to do this to reduce the cost but just to centralize the implementation. Does Microsoft allow something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Serilog for logging, you can remove the Application Insight from your API application and  Website. When we use Application Insight in our project, it creates files and add code to some of our files.

To remove Application Insight, you'll need to first remove the NuGet packages and references from your application. We can uninstall NuGet packages by following any of the two following approaches:

### Unistall using NuGet

To uninstall Application Insight, in the top menu select **Tools** > **NuGet Package Manager** > **Package Manager Console**.

Then enter the command :

```
Uninstall-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web
-RemoveDependencies
```

### Remove using Visual Studio NuGet UI

For step by step approach for this process and the above mentioned process check the following MS Document.
[How to remove Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/remove-application-insights?tabs=net).

The above mentioned approach will help you in removing the Application Insight, also could you please elaborate your question for more better understanding.

Comment: The thing is that Azure Application Insights is a subscription-based product that is configured in an ASP.NET project. We pay for API and Website projects separately. While I am thinking of moving it to the shared C# project and then use it in two ASP.NET projects from the shared project. 

I don't want to do this to reduce the cost but just to centralize the implementation. Does Microsoft allow something like this?

Comment: The issue with centralized implementation is that, if its a shared assembly, the same assembly will be loaded into 2 different projects. There will be multiple independent paths(threads) writing to app insights.
As for the question, yes it should just work.